# In Ember, should I put my theme layout in application.hbs or index.html?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I started working on Ember js using ember-cli and I want to migrate an existing code written in html, jquery and css. I am not sure if its best to put it in the index.html or application.hbs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to put your code in `application.hbs`, except of tags which need to be put in `<head>` tag.

You can see that in `index.html` you have HTMLBars expression:

```
{{content-for 'body'}}
```

It's where your generated HTML application code is put, but first, it's wrapped in ember wrapper div, inside of which your application events are handled.

Imagine that you have put one of your divs in `index.html` - let's call it `.main-div`, then - in `application.hbs` - you've put code which has some Ember logic(so you can't put it in `index.html` too). Now, imagine you write CSS code to target one of children of `.main-div`. You target it like this in your CSS: `.main-div > .dynamic-div`, but it won't work. Why? Ember wrapped contents of `application.hbs` in its div and it's one level down. That's why it would be against developer intuition to put application HTML code in `index.html` - it could bite you if you forget that you have one layer more of Ember code even if in your editor you see it should be straight: `.main-div > .dynamic-div`.

Example of Ember.js wrapper div:

```
<div id="ember463" class="ember-view">
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably your `application.hbs` file. As mentioned in [the Ember CLI guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#appindexhtml), the `index.html` file is mostly for addons to inject their scripts. You don't need to go that route though. You can manage your legacy Javascript and CSS using the Broccoli asset pipeline and you can put any legacy/common HTML in your `application.hbs` file.